# Saving SparkXGBoost model yields empty directory

Tags: pyspark, xgboost

I'm trying to save a SparkXGBoost model using the following code (based on [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/spark_estimator.html)):

`model_1.save("/tmp/xgboost-pyspark-model")`

The model was trained on a dataset and returns correct predictions. However, the directories created by the code (`xgboost-pyspark-model/metadata` and `xgboost-pyspark-model/model`) are empty (only `_SUCCESS` files are there). When I try to load the model:

`model_2 = SparkXGBClassifier.load("./models/xgboost-pyspark-model")`

I'm, getting the following error:

`ValueError: RDD is empty`

I tried to save the model using `model.write().overwrite().save()` code as well. The same result.

Comment: Seeing the same issue running xgboost-2.0.0.dev on pySpark3.3/python3.8.

Comment: Filed this issue: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/9446